# Why does hibernate strictly asks to define the hibernate.dialect property while the JPA specification doesn't makes it mandatory?

Tags: hibernate, jpa-2.1

While learning about java persistence using hibernate I found that hibernate made it mandatory to define dialect property. I'm confused that SQL is the common language and its used for DB communication, why should we go for different dialects for different DBs? Why should hibernate strictly asking for defining the dialect while JPA specification doesn't care about it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually **Hibernate** *does not need* the `hibernate.dialect` property to be set.

Have a look what the documentation says in chapter 7.12: http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#database-dialect

> 7.12. Database Dialect
>
> Although SQL is relatively standardized, each database vendor uses a
>   subset and superset of ANSI SQL defined syntax. This is referred to as
>   the database’s dialect. Hibernate handles variations across these
>   dialects through its org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect class and the
>   various subclasses for each database vendor.
>
> In most cases Hibernate will be able to determine the proper Dialect
>   to use by asking some questions of the JDBC Connection during
>   bootstrap. For information on Hibernate’s ability to determine the
>   proper Dialect to use (and your ability to influence that resolution),
>   see Dialect resolution.
>
> If for some reason it is not able to determine the proper one or you
>   want to use a custom Dialect, you will need to set the
>   hibernate.dialect setting.

Comment: Thanks simon. That was very useful.